# Find index of last occurrence of each distinct zipcode in collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Given a class:

```
public class Data {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
}
```

And given the below list where there are three distinct zipcodes: `["21112" ,"21046", "21075"]`

```
var items = new List<Data> {
    new Data { name = "bob", gender = "male", zipcode = "21112" }
    new Data { name = "sarah", gender = "female", zipcode = "21046" }
    new Data { name = "steven", gender = "male", zipcode = "21112" }
    new Data { name = "joe", gender = "male", zipcode = "21046" }
    new Data { name = "karen", gender = "female", zipcode = "21075" }
}
```

If I order the list by zipcode, how can I find the index (the zero-based index of an item in the collection) of the last occurrence of each distinct zipcode:

```
items.OrderBy(i => i.zipcode)??
```

I need the index because I need to insert an item after each index. I get a collection of `Data` and I need to modify it before returning.

Comment: By index I mean the zero-based index of an item in the collection.

Comment: Why would you get an index ? Instead, don't you prefer a `Data` object ?

Comment: I need the index because I need to insert an item after each index. I get a collection of `Data` and I need to modify it before returning.

Comment: There is not a way to order it in the way that I need. In other words, for each zipcode I'm inserting an item in the collection that has no discernible way to order it in the position that I need (which is at the end of each zipcode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you will need both the zip code and the index you can either use an anonymous type or a tuple. Here is an example with the former:

```
items.GroupBy(i => i.zipcode).Select(list => new 
{ 
    ZipCode = list.Last().zipcode, 
    Index = items.IndexOf(list.Last()) 
});
```

If you want you can use the query comprehension syntax and use a let clause to specify the last element, so that LINQ won't possibly iterate over the list twice

```
var insertions = from item in items
                 group item by item.zipcode into grouped
                 let last = grouped.Last()
                 select new 
                 {
                     ZipCode = last.zipcode,
                     Index = items.IndexOf(last)
                  };
```

As you will need to update the original list with the indexes you might need to materialize the insertions enumerable *before* updating the original table, or you will incur in an exception. In order to do that simply add a .ToList() at the end of the clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
items.GroupBy(i => i.ZipCode).Select(group => items.IndexOf(group.Last()));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not nearly as elegant as other answers, and possibly not as efficient, either, but may be helpful anyway so here it goes:

`List<T>.OrderBy()` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable`, which can have `.ToList()` called on it like any other IEnumerable.  So you can do:

```
List<Data> orderedList = items.OrderBy(i => i.zipcode).ToList(); //outputs a plain list in the sorted order
List<string> distinctZipCodes = (from i in orderedList select i.zipcode).Distinct(); //get a list of distinct zip codes
foreach(string s in DistinctZipCodes)
{
     int index = orderedList.FindLastIndex((e)=> {return (e.zipcode== s);}); //get last index of each zip
     //do something with index
}
```